# ImageMagick Linux mimick ezgif.com result

Tags: imagemagick

Ezgif.com is a great page but can ImageMagick get the same results?

> Ezgif settings:

```
Delay: 200 per image
Crossfade frames 
Fader delay: 6 
Frame Count: 10
```

My attempt via Linux Terminal:

```
convert -delay 200 -loop 0 *.jpg myimage.gif
```

Comment: Imagemagick does not do any fading when creating an animated gif. But you can do that in Imagemagick. See my scripts, fxtransitions and transitions at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick. To fade, you just have to create intermediate frames by blending between two images using -set option:compose:args=XX -compose blend -composite. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#blend

Comment: That is some really advanced things! but I am unsure how to combine what you said with my code I added since I dont use 2 images but several images that should one by one go to the next one, my attempt is like this but I dont see any big difference convert -delay 150 -set option:compose:args=30,100 -compose *.jpg -composite -loop 0 *.jpg myimage.gif

Comment: You have to loop over each pair and create new intermediate images for the fade using -compose blend, etc. Then when done, create the animation as in your original command from all the images you created. Looping means scripting and that is OS dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i told you on FL, you need to simply use

```
convert -resize (Smallest size) -delay 200 -morph 200 (source) (destination)
```

e.g:

```
convert -resize 200x200 -delay 200 -morph 200 /var/home/user1/pictures/*.jpg /var/home/user1/myresult.gif
```

on my side i can show you the result like this used on WINDOWS

in Windows Pictures folder
used this command:

```
C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures>convert -resize 20% -delay 20 -loop 0 *.jpg -morph 5 myimage.gif
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is a good solution. I forgot about morph.

Comment: It didnt work first but when I copied the Windows example it worked flawlessly with a simple liner, great work and thanks!

Comment: anytime, i was trying to reach you on FL but there is always an error, anyway goodluck =)

Answer (score 1):

Here is Unix shell script to create a faded animation of 4 images each with 10 intermediate fades. It loops over each successive pair of images and creates the faded intermediate images by blending the pair at different percentages.

Input:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
(
imgArr=(lena.jpg mandril3.jpg zelda1.jpg peppers.jpg)
for ((i=0; i<4; i++)); do
    img1=${imgArr[$i]}
    j=$((i+1))
    jj=$((j%4))
    img2=${imgArr[$jj]}
    for ((k=0; k<11; k++)); do
        pct=$((10*k))
        convert $img1 $img2 -define compose:args=$pct -compose blend -composite miff:-
    done
done
) | convert -delay 20 - -loop 0 anim.gif
```

Animation:

[image]

Note that I had to shrink the image to 75% dimensions to make the file size small enough for upload here.

Comment: I got this error in Ubuntu 16.04 when I execute it, I use Ubuntu non graphical interface if that matters. 
convert: ImageSequenceRequired `-composite' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageList/7863.
convert: no images defined `miff:-' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
c

Comment: Did you copy exactly?  Note the leading and trailing parentheses. These are for subshell processing and are needed. The images are collected in the miff:- structure without saving to disk in the subshell processing and then piped to the last convert line. So it must be copied properly

Comment: Also be careful that there are no new line character changes.

Comment: What version of Imagemagick. If using IM 7 change `convert` to `magick`

Comment: Put in echo >&2 statements to check on variables

Comment: It works, I made a mistake when copying. Only thing that I find missing from this code is to seperate how long a picture is displayed and how fast the animation transisition is, it seems to be the same setting

Comment: I could achieve that by duplicating the images, so in the imgArr I just put lena.jpg lena.jpg lena.jpg and ofcourse change array size in the code

Answer (score 0):

A complete one-liner solution with increased delay for main frames and last-to-first transition, with the same settings OP asked:

```
convert -loop 0 *.jpg -morph 10 -set delay '%[fx:(t%11!=0)?6:200]' -duplicate 1,-2-1 out.gif
```

*`-morph 10` inserts 10 intermediate frames between every original frame, so we need to increase the delay time for every 11th frame, so the `fx` part sets different delay time for them.*

*`-duplicate 1,-2-1` does the transition for last to first frame*